# Como comparar mais de uma coluna numa clausula IN?

Tags: sql-server

Existe uma maneira de comparar >= 2 colunas em uma cláusula [`IN`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/in-function.php) tipo como se fosse comparar objetos?

Por exemplo(Vai dar erro por isso a pergunta)

```
SELECT * FROM Usuarios1 WHERE Nome,Sobrenome IN(SELECT Nome,Sobrenome from Usuarios2);
```

ou seria algo do tipo

`SELECT * FROM Usuarios1 WHERE Nome,Sobrenome IN(('Leo','Bonetti'),('José','Silva'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente, não há como usar o `IN` para comparar registros por mais de uma coluna. Porém, você pode criar uma tabela anônima a partir de uma subquery e fazer um join nas colunas equivalentes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Usuarios1 este
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Nome, Sobrenome 
  FROM Usuarios2) outro
ON este.Nome = outro.Nome AND este.Sobrenome = outro.Sobrenome
```